# Most "pythonic" way of organising class attributes, constructor arguments and subclass constructor defaults?

Tags: python, python-2.6

Being relatively new to Python 2, I'm uncertain how best to organise my class files in the most 'pythonic' way. I wouldn't be asking this but for the fact that Python seems to have quite a few ways of doing things that are very different to what I have come to expect from the languages I am used to.

Initially, I was just treating classes how I'd usually treat them in C# or PHP, which of course made me trip up all over the place when I eventually discovered the mutable values gotcha:

```
class Pants(object):
    pockets = 2
    pocketcontents = []

class CargoPants(Pants):
    pockets = 200

p1 = Pants()
p1.pocketcontents.append("Magical ten dollar bill")
p2 = CargoPants()

print p2.pocketcontents
```

Yikes! Didn't expect that!

I've spent a lot of time searching the web and through some source for other projects for hints on how best to arrange my classes, and one of the things I noticed was that people seem to declare a lot of their instance variables - mutable or otherwise - in the constructor, and also pile the default constructor arguments on quite thickly.

After developing like this for a while, I'm still left scratching my head a bit about the unfamiliarity of it. Considering the lengths to which the python language goes to to make things seem more intuitive and obvious, it seems outright odd to me in the few cases where I've got quite a lot of attributes or a lot of default constructor arguments, especially when I'm subclassing:

```
class ClassWithLotsOfAttributes(object):
    def __init__(self, jeebus, coolness='lots', python='isgoodfun', 
             pythonic='nebulous', duck='goose', pants=None, 
             magictenbucks=4, datawad=None, dataload=None,
             datacatastrophe=None):

        if pants is None: pants = []
        if datawad is None: datawad = []
        if dataload is None: dataload = []
        if datacatastrophe is None: datacatastrophe = []
        self.coolness = coolness
        self.python = python
        self.pythonic = pythonic
        self.duck = duck
        self.pants = pants
        self.magictenbucks = magictenbucks
        self.datawad = datawad
        self.dataload = dataload
        self.datacatastrophe = datacatastrophe
        self.bigness = None
        self.awesomeitude = None
        self.genius = None
        self.fatness = None
        self.topwise = None
        self.brillant = False
        self.strangenessfactor = 3
        self.noisiness = 12
        self.whatever = None
        self.yougettheidea = True

class Dog(ClassWithLotsOfAttributes):
    def __init__(self, coolness='lots', python='isgoodfun', pythonic='nebulous', duck='goose', pants=None, magictenbucks=4, datawad=None, dataload=None, datacatastrophe=None):
        super(ClassWithLotsOfAttributes, self).__init__(coolness, python, pythonic, duck, pants, magictenbucks, datawad, dataload, datacatastrophe)
        self.noisiness = 1000000

    def quack(self):
        print "woof"
```

Mild silliness aside (I can't really help myself when cooking up these artificial example classes), assuming I have a real-world need for a set of classes with this many attributes, I suppose my questions are:

- What is the most, uhh, 'pythonic' way of declaring a class with that many attributes? Is it best to put them against the class if the default is immutable, ala Pants.pockets, or is it better to put them in the constructor, ala ClassWithLotsOfAttributes.noisiness?
- Is there a way to eliminate the need to redeclare the defaults for all of the subclass constructor arguments, as in Dog.__init__? Should I even be including this many arguments with defaults anyway?

Comment: +1 Gotta love your example attributes. Also, good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If attributes will vary from instance
  to instance make them instance
  attribute i.e. create them
  inside`__init__` using **self** else if they need to
  be shared between class instances
  like a constant, put them at class
  level.
- If your class really need to pass, so
  many arguments in `__init__`, let
  derive class use argument list and
  keyword arguments e.g.

```
class Dog(ClassWithLotsOfAttributes):
    def __init__(self, *args , **kwargs):
        super(ClassWithLotsOfAttributes,    self).__init__(*args , **kwargs)
        self.coolness = "really cool!!!
```

- No need of passing all variables except few important ones, in
  `__init__`, class can assume some
  defaults and user can change them
  later on if needed.
- Use 4 spaces instead of tab.
- if you need to add an extra arg bite, to Dog and keyword arg old too

```
class CoolDog(ClassWithLotsOfAttributes):
    def __init__(self, bite, *args , **kwargs):
        self.old = kwargs.pop('old', False) # this way we can access base class args too
        super(ClassWithLotsOfAttributes,    self).__init__(*args , **kwargs)
        self.bite = bite
        self.coolness = "really really cool!!!
```

various ways you useCoolDog

```
CoolDog(True)
CoolDog(True, old=False)
CoolDog(bite=True, old=True)
CoolDog(old=True, bite=False)
```

Comment: oh i didn't know you could use the *args and **kwargs in that way! 'coolness' most definitely needs to be upped to 'really cool!!!' :)

Comment: also, what about the case where Dog.__init__ needs to add an extra constructor argument? is def__init__(self, legs=4, *args, **kwargs) the right way to go about it?

Comment: yes you can specifically check of var name in kargs, i will add an example

Comment: “make them instance attribute i.e. create them inside__init__” -> What really matters is to use `self` instead of the class. I think it may be misleading for beginners.

Comment: what is the main difference between self.old = kwargs.pop('old', False) and def __init__(self, bite, old=False, *args, **kwargs) ?

Comment: no difference you can actually use that, but I added pop so that you can actually get access to base class arguments too if needed

Comment: In the second case, `old` will take up one positional argument position (so you specify it as the second argument unless you specify arguments by name.) Extracting it from the keyword arguments dictionary, it can't be a positional argument which is sometimes desired for arguments.