# How to not put self. when initializing every attribute in a Python class?

Tags: python

Greetings.
I searched for a long time, and found many related questions with no answer for me. Despite mine seems to be a simple beginner doubt.

We have a (I guess) typical class definition:

```
class Town:
    def __init__(self, Name, Ruler = "Spanish Inquisition"):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Population = 0
        self.LocationX = 0
        self.LocationY = 0
        self.Religion = "Jedi"
        self.Ruler = Ruler
        self.Products = ["Redstone", "Azaleas"]
```

You get the idea. A lot of attributes. I need all of them.

The question is: **Is there a shortcut to save all those "self."?** Am I being too lazy? I hoped for something like:

```
with self:
    Name = Name
    Population = 0
    ...
```

which of course I know does not work (this is not the use of "with", and arguments are in a wrong namespace. ... I got it right?).

I guess there are a lot of alternatives to achieve the same result, but I'm really curious about the power of Python classes, and I think other people asked about this with no success.

(A related question: [Most "pythonic" way of organising class attributes, constructor arguments and subclass constructor defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118006/most-pythonic-way-of-organising-class-attributes-constructor-arguments-and-su) )

Comment: If you run into this problem a lot, I would suggest seeing if your text editor allows you to create macros. Type one attribute name per line (so, one line would just show `name`), then run the macros on the lines to change `name` into `self.name = name`. Also, you should try to get into the habit of using the correct naming conventions. All those arguments and attributes [should be lowercase](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Add one vote to 'just type `self`'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't. It's mandatory to use `self` when accessing an instance member (attribute, method) in Python.

A clarification: `self` is not a keyword in Python. In principle you could give the first parameter of a method any name, but convention mandates that you should call it `self`.

Comment: @deathApril Technically true, but since  the convention is `self`, using something else makes your code harder to read, maintain, and work with.  The convention is so ingrained that you'll have problems with code autocomplete and formatting tools if you use something else.

Comment: Despite there being no way to avoid `self`, there certainly is a way to avoid *retyping* it...

Answer (score 5):

You won't make any friends, but one way....:

```
class Town2:
    def __init__(self, name, ruler = 'Spider Pig'):
        self.__dict__.update(dict(
            Name = name,
            Population = 0,
            LocationX = 0,
            LocationY = 0,
            Religion = "Jedi",
            Ruler = ruler,
            Products = ["Redstone", "Azaleas"]))
```

Comment: The baby Jesus, he is crying.  Also, this will hose most attempts to use properties or other descriptors.

Comment: Ruler should just be Homer. Spider Pig !

Comment: @sr2222 indeed - but then hopefully it will dawn that typing `self.` isn't that hard... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can avoid all the excessive `self`, typing while keeping in tune with DRY:

```
class Town(object):
    def __init__(self, name, data={}):
        setattr(self, 'name', name)
        for k,v in data.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)


default_town_info = {
    'population': 0,
    'location_x': 0,
    'location_y': 0
    }

a = Town('foo', default_town_info)
print a.name
print a.population
print a.location_x
```

This would still allow you to access your attributes, returning:

```
foo
0
0
```

So yes, there are 2 self uses, but it can be reduced if you always pass a dictionary that ensures the attributes you require are provided, e.g., 'name'.

Comment: That's the power of dictionaries, more than classes'. I shall give it a try. Thank you too!